# Is this possible to add div id like this in a href tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, hyperlink

In a form how to get the datetime from user input with PHP Insert Into MySQL

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2">DoB:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="birth">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('input[name=birth]').val()` use attr selector with `.val()`

Comment: "Is this possible to add div id like this in a href tag"?  i cant see how that match anything in your code

Comment: sorry i can't able edit..

Comment: @GuruRagav yes you can edit your own OP